# Mark a lead duplicate and assign to owner of original lead

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to match Lead based on email address and Phone.
If there is a match found then mark the status of lead as duplicate and owner should be same as existing lead owner.
I have written the below method and it is working for Email field.
What is the best way to do it for Phone if Email field is blank? Should I create one more map for Phone as key.
PS: I am a beginner in Programming. Thanks in Advance.

```
 private void checkDuplicateLeads() {
    Set<String> EmailSet = new Set<String>();
    Map<String,Lead> ExistingLeadMap = new Map<String,Lead>();
    for(Lead l : (List<Lead>) Trigger.new) {
        if (l.Email != null){
             EmailSet.add(l.Email);
        }
    }
    for (Lead l2 : [SELECT Email,OwnerId,Owner.Type,Phone FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :EmailSet]) {
        ExistingLeadMap.put(l2.Email, l2);
    }
    for(Lead l3: (List<Lead>) Trigger.new){

        if(ExistingLeadMap.containsKey(l3.Email)){
            l3.Status='Duplicate Lead';
            if(ExistingLeadMap.get(l3.Email).Owner.Type=='User'){
                l3.OwnerId=ExistingLeadMap.get(l3.Email).Ownerid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the standard `Duplicate Management` [feature](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, Leads will be inserted through API/Web-to-Leads.
Business wants to allow the creation of leads (we don't want to prevent duplicate) and assign it to same owner as existing leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need another map. You should add a filter on `Status` to your query.

Here are a couple helper methods that can clean up your code a bit.

```
public static final String DUPE_STATUS = 'Duplicate Lead';
public static Set<String> pluckStrings(List<Lead> records, SObjectField field)
{
    Set<String> values = new Set<String>();
    for (Lead record : records) values.add((String)record.get(field));
    values.remove(null);
    return values;
}
static void checkDuplicate(Lead original, Lead candidate)
{
    if (candidate == null) return;
    original.Status = DUPE_STATUS;
    if (candidate.Owner.Type == 'User')
        original.OwnerId = candidate.OwnerId;
}
```

Then you can make your method:

```
public static void checkDuplicateLeads(List<Lead> records)
{
    Map<String, Lead> emailToLead = new Map<String, Lead>();
    Map<String, Lead> phoneToLead = new Map<String, Lead>();
    for (Lead record : [
        SELECT Email, Phone, OwnerId, Onwer.Type FROM Lead
        WHERE Status != DUPE_STATUS
        AND (
            Email IN :pluckStrings(records, Lead.Email)
            OR Phone IN :pluckStrings(records, Lead.Phone)
        )
    ]){
        emailToLead.put(record.Email, record);
        phoneToLead.put(record.Phone, record);
    }
    for(Lead record : records)
    {
        if (emailToLead.containsKey(record.Email))
            checkDuplicate(record, emailToLead.get(record.Email));
        else
            checkDuplicate(record, phoneToLead.get(record.Phone));
    }
}
```